# Controlling an application's API access to a SharePoint site

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I have an external program that I have scheduled to run once a day (i.e. no user interaction). This program should upload a file to a SharePoint Online site, using Microsoft Graph API. I'm able to enable this in Azure Active Directory by registering an app, and giving this app the application permission `File.ReadWrite.All`, then sending a PUT request to
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content`

However, by granting `File.ReadWrite.All`, the program will have access to all files in all site collections for my organization. I want to limit access to a specific site, or perhaps just a specific folder within that site. How can this be achieved? (without the need for a user to interactively sign in when the program is run)

Comment: are you married to using Graph? Is you set up an SharePoint app-only context you'll have more options, and if you use a service account credential (an AAD account with non-expiring password and no O365 license) you'll have even more.

Comment: @DerekGusoff Do you have links that explains these options?

Answer (score 1):

Edit (2021-03-04): This is possible now: https://developer.microsoft.com/office/blogs/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/

<strike>It is not currently possible to restrict app-only access to a specific SharePoint site, through Microsoft Graph.</strike>

Comment: Is this still the case?  if an azure app has the application permission Sites.Read.All, it appears that it can read everything, was hoping that we could limit it somehow to just certain sites and control which sites using the appinv.aspx permissions XML context but it doesn't seem to be working this way.  If an azure app has this application permission it seems to be able to see all sites!

Comment: To my knowledge, yes, this is till the case.

Comment: @Becker This is no longer the case: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/

Comment: Is this available? I have looked in our "Select API permissions" under Microsoft Graph API but Sites.selected is nowhere to be found. Is there some setting i need to enable to have this accessable?

Comment: @Sultanen You might be looking under "Delegated permissions". Sites.Selected is an app role, listed under "Application permissions".