# How do i scope a Azure Portal registered app to only have access to a specific calendar in sharepoint, Using MS Graph

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am setting up a WebAPI that needs to collect events from a calendar, located in sharepoint. The WebAPI is registered i Azure Portal and does not support user login. Can i restrict the application to only that one calendar, or only have access to a specific users calendars?

This is what i currently have.

- A WebAPI ( .Net Core 2.1 )
- Azure AD with a bunch of users
- Registered in Azure Portal, with Application "Calendars.Read" permissions
- Using TenantID/ClientID/ClientSecret when authentication the app, and have not user login for the webserver, and would prefer not to have user login if possible.

As of now, i can pull the events with Microsoft graph by using something like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/4bddc7ee-xyz-xyz-83cc-/blablabla
```

The problem is that i have access to all users calendars, and i need to restrict the app to only have access to that specific calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen several similar questions like this, the answer is No,  Microsoft Graph does not support that currently.

Comment: If you could add an link to an official statement about this, i can mark this as answered

Comment: @LosMadsen No official doc, I have seen a similar issue, a guy who works in the Azure AD team point that.

Comment: @LosMadsen This is the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56073788/controlling-an-applications-api-access-to-a-sharepoint-site/56082082#56082082